# I am 170 cm tall and i am only 47 kgs. How to increse my weight??I have not tried any proper exercise.

Tags: bodyweight-exercises

What are the possible ways to increase my weight with proper body shape??

Comment: Have you tried eating more food than you already do..?

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem like a COMPLETE beginner, I'm going to make this really easy for you.

The ONLY way to increase your bodyweight is to eat more calories than you burn. Simple right? Now before you think "well I don't exercise anyways so I don't burn any calories", you have to understand that your body burns calories on its own everyday just to make your body function properly. This is what is referred to as your resting metabolic rate (or metabolism ...doesn't really matter to narrow down at this point). You weigh 47kgs, so that means your metabolic rate is probably around 1500 calories roughly. So if you ate less than this on a regular basis, you won't gain weight. Basically...just eat a lot more than 1500 calories and you will gain weight, you don't really need to count, just ballpark.

Second, you say "proper" body shape, I assume this means you want muscle. Well...muscle isn't weightless obviously, so in order to gain muscle, you must first eat more than you burn like I said above. The rest is very simple. Go to the gym and workout. There are millions of workout guides online for beginners, it would be naive to give you only one way on this site. Go look it up and pick one. The way this works is when you lift weights, you're breaking down muscle fibers (catabolism). Now, when you eat an excess of calories (primarily composed of protein), these muscles are built back, bigger and stronger via the calories you just fed them (anabolism). One key to this process is that in order for this to work, you must feed your body the correct building blocks, called amino acids and you get these from your proteins; milk,chicken,beef,eggs,tuna,whey and on.

Moreover, your body must have adequate time to do this building process. This means you need to sleep and sleep often. This is typically around 7-8 hours minimum to be safe. The muscle growth happens when your recovering, and you recover when you're sleeping.

So to very naively conclude:

Eat more than you burn. And then eat some more. This is fundamental to gaining weight.

When you do eat more, make sure the majority of your calories come from protein. A basic guideline is to consume a gram of protein per lbs of bodyweight, so in your case, aim for at least 105g.

Go to the gym and lift weights.

Sleep, rest, repeat.

It really is THAT simple, I'm not going to write an article on all the things you need to do because what I mentioned above is basically 99% of it. The rest just comes to consistency and dedication.

Again: **EAT**, **LIFT**, **EAT MORE**, AND **SLEEP**.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to keep it even simpler. Your question boils down to "lean-gains".

1. Eat
2. Workout
3. Eat
4. Sleep

I can guarantee you aren't eating enough.